# How to create document relationships between regular collection and timeseries collection in PyMongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, relationship, fastapi, pydantic

I have a regular user collection in mongodb, modeled by pydantic as follows:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4, alias="_id")
    username: str
    email: str
    password: str

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "_id": "066de609-b04a-4b30-b46c-32537c7f1f6e",
                "username": "username",
                "email": "user@mail.com",
                "password": "randomHashedPassword"
            }
        }
```

I also have a timeseries userdata collection that I am yet to model in pydantic.
The metaField points to the metadata field and this field will contain the particular user's ID so that I can reference and populate the user when I am querying the userdata collection.

What would be the best way to handle this? With SQLAlchemy and relational databases, I could create a relationship with foreign keys, which do not really apply to document-based databases. What similar concept should I look into for mongodb?

Should I create an aggregation pipeline instead and have just the user ID in the metadata field to lookup by?

I don't want to use ODMantic unless I have absolutely have to as that's another dependency alongside pydantic.